# how to show databases name in codeigniter 3

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3, php-7

hy everyone, can I get list of databases name in mysql server on codeigniter3
I have tried this codeigniter3 query code but still not worked:

```
$databases = $this->db->query('show databases');
```

I also tried with php code not worked

```
$db_conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$databases = mysqli_query($db_conn,"SHOW DATABASES");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can easily fetch the all database related information in codeigniter by:-

Just use below code:-

```
print_r($this->db);
```

Just Only fetch the database name then:-

```
echo $this->db->database;
```